# How to integrate with respect to additive measure

Tags: reference-request

I would like  references about theory of integrals of real functions with respect to additive (not necessary countable additive) measures defined on a field of sets.

Comment: [Dunford and Schwartz](http://books.google.com/books?id=sqRuPgAACAAJ), for example.

Comment: [Dunford & Schwartz - Linear Operators](http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Operators-General-Classics-Library/dp/0471608483) develops some theory of integration with respect to additive measures. (Damn, I'm slow. =))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Theory of charges: a study of finitely additive measures](http://books.google.com/books/about/Theory_of_charges.html?id=mTNQvfe54CoC) by K. P. S. Bhaskara Rao and M. Bhaskara Rao.